# Why is the SLAB service warning of dropped events for my ETW event source?

Tags: trace, system.diagnostics, etw, etw-eventsource

I'm getting this error on one of my servers:

```
EventId : 806, Level : Warning, Message : Some events will be lost because of bu
ffer overruns or schema synchronization delays in trace session: Microsoft-Seman
ticLogging-Etw-Mobile2ConsoleListener., Payload : [sessionName : Microsoft-Seman
ticLogging-Etw-Mobile2ConsoleListener] , EventName : TraceEventServiceEventsWill
BeLostInfo, Timestamp : 2014-02-28T10:38:46.6527952Z
```

I have another server which I *think* is set up identically. However, when I run the ETW SLAB service to listen for ETW events emitting from my event source I get the above warning but not on the other server. What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when I pass a null value for a string payload ...  see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246261/risk-of-missing-events-from-etw-logging-with-eventsource) on etw ...